# NSAutoLayout: How to add element dynamically

Tags: cocoa-touch, autolayout

I need to add an undefined number of `NSButton` to an NSView in code. The problem is that I can' t use `constraintsWithVisualFormat:` because i don' t know the name of the `NSButton` and also the number of button that I have. Anyone have a solution? Thanks!

Comment: I think that I can create dinamically the string used in the `constraintsWithVisualFormat:` method but can I do that if I have an array of `NSButton`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using `constraintsWithVisualFormat:`, you need to know the names of the variables that point to your NSButtons *only* if you use `NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings` to create the dictionary of views.  You could just as easily build your own dictionary using whatever keys you like.

If your buttons are stored in an array, you can iterate through them and create constraints between each of them:

```
for ( int i = 1 ; i < buttonArray.count ; i++ ) {
    NSDictionary* views = @{ @"buttonOne":buttonArray[i-1] , @"buttonTwo":buttonArray[i] } ;
    NSArray* constraints = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"[buttonOne]-[buttonTwo]"  options:0  metrics:nil  views:views] ;
    // Use the constraints.
}
```

Comment: Yes, I found the solution before your reply but this is exactly what I need. Thanks again!